# Is it a good idea to put "export BASH_ENV=~/.bashrc" in my .bashrc?

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, environment-variables

Let's say my Bash has some extensive `~/.bashrc` customization that aids me not only in interactive use, but also in scripting (aliases, functions, variables, etc.). I would like to have this available to all my scripts, so I was thinking of setting `BASH_ENV` to `~/.bashrc` (Which seems to be the way to do it.)

My question is, is there any problem with this?

- One concern is that any third-party shell script I use might conflict with my `~/.bashrc`. But I see that as a manageable problem, as I would vet them before using them anyway (or blindly trust in esoteric statistics like Github stars to deem them safe), and only occasionally lowering myself to unsetting `BASH_ENV` for any script that might be misbehaving.
- Another concern is speed, but honestly, my `~/.bashrc` is not that heavy, and if I wanted speed, I wouldn't be using a shell script.
- Another concern is safety. But If I run a malicious script with some sort of setuid or privileged status, I am already living the YOLO lifestyle, and my `~/.bashrc` would only be a mild condiment to the main course of my utter ganking.
- Another concern is that, from a purist point of view, it might be  better to split my `~/.bashrc` into two files, one for interactive use and one for scripting, and maybe set it so that the interactive one is a superset of the scripting one. But that sounds like too much work for too little gain, except for the fuzzy feeling of purity.
- Another concern is portability, but I'm writing scripts mostly for myself. If I want to share them with others later, it wouldn't be that hard to generalize. If things come to worse, I can always write a script to automatically inline whatever `~/.bashrc` features I'm using. That doesn't sound like an NP problem.
- It could also be argued that my approach is flawed, since any script that might benefit from non-standard features of my `~/.bashrc`, indicates that such a script should be written in another language to begin with.
- On the other side, the Unix/Linux philosophy is not just a set of standards, but a set of tools to customize your environment to your needs, so why not.

Comment: "I see that as a manageable problem, as I would vet them before using them anyway" ... really? You'd be surprised at how many tools are scripts or wrapper scripts. On my Arch Linux installation, something like 200/1700 files in `/usr/bin` are scripts. And that's not even accounting for helper scripts in `/usr/lib` and the like.

Comment: Baroque question phrasing is your choice and i am almost certain that it is a reflection of your enthusiasm, so this comment is no criticism. However if you want to attract attention AND get good answersss, make your questions short and easy to parse. This said you got one good answer and one good comment (not mine) already, so ... not too bad considering. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO, no it's not a good idea.

You'd be better off explicitly sourcing your library of functions and variables (aliases don't work in non-interactive shells unless the `expand_aliases` shell option is set) at the top of each script that uses it - that way you don't risk breaking (loudly & obviously or, worse, subtly) any of the hundreds or thousands of existing scripts on your system.

However, as always, the ultimate rule is: it's your system, you can break it if you want to.